# string comparison with double?

Tags: c#, linq, double

Hi im trying to do a string match for some certain things in my webservice however I get stuck at comparing a double

```
public List<Customers> GetCustomer(string anything)
{
    List<Customers> customers = customermembers.Where(n =>
    string.Equals(n.CustomerID, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    || string.Equals(n.FirstName, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    || string.Equals(n.LastName, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    || double.Equals(n.Age, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) //this like
    ).ToList();
    return customers;
}
```

How do you compare a double?

My DataContract looks like this:

```
[DataMember(Name = "Age")]
public double Age { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm not quire sure why you want to compare a string with a double and whether this is legal ?

Comment: Not sure why you would use a double for the age. How old are you expecting these customers to be?!

Comment: @KirstyWhite dont get me wrong but you cannot say in a real world that a person's age is e.g. 25.56

Comment: So I should just stick with string? I could just use a regular expression on the client side to not put illegal non numeric data in.

Comment: No, use something more in keeping with your data needs. Like a short. I can't believe none of the answers are not suggesting getting rid of the double!

Comment: OK, to all the answers here, who would seriously think using a double for an age is a good idea? Unless you were talking about the age of universe in seconds!

Comment: @LeeTaylor: In some business calculations (e.g. actuary calculations) you may want to use a fractional age. I assume the Kirsty has good reason to use a fractional age. Now, using a floating point number is maybe not the best choice but it is hard to know without more information.

Comment: Ideally one should store birthdates and not ages....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you compare a double?

I assume that you want to compare two double values representing age and that `anything` is indeed not a `string` but a `double` (it is a bit hard to tell from the question because the way `anything` is used doesn't make much sense).

Best thing you can do is to switch the type of `Age` from `double` to `decimal` (or even better `int` if the age is an integer). Doing that avoid rounding errors.

However, if you want to stick to floating point numbers you can simply compare two `double` values using `==`:

```
a == b
```

or use the static `object.Equals` method:

```
Equals(a, b)
```

If you perform calculations on the ages you will probably get rounding problems and then you will have to use a small *epsilon* value that represents the rounding precision you want to use:

```
const double Epsilon = 0.0000000001;
var areEqual = Math.Abs(a - b) < Epsilon;
```

Comment: Thanks Martin that explored what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
public bool DoubleEqualsString(double doubleValue, string stringValue)
{
    double convertedValue;
    if (Double.TryParse(stringValue, out convertedValue))
        return convertedValue == doubleValue;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
double double1 = Age;
```

with

```
string double1 = Age.ToString();
```

then in your comparison use:

```
string.Equals(double1, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Do not use a double for the age.

Answer (score 0):

Convert double to String before doing a comparision. Try this: Replace last line of the query to

```
|| String.Equals(SqlFunctions.StringConvert(n.Age), anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Says sqlfunctions does not exist in the current context?

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.Data.Objects.SqlClient namespace?

Comment: I dont have it. That will be why.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a function that tries to parse your string to a double and returns -1 for "no luck"?

```
 public double ParseAge(string age){
      double parsedAge = -1;
      Double.TryParse(age, out parsedAge);
      return parsedAge;
 }

 public List<Customers> GetCustomer(string anything)
 {
    double double1 = Age;
    List<Customers> customers = customermembers.Where(n =>
                                       string.Equals(n.CustomerID, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                       || string.Equals(n.FirstName, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                       || string.Equals(n.LastName, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                       || n.Age == ParseAge(anything) //this like
                                   ).ToList();
    return customers;
 }
```

Comment: Do not use a double for the age.

Comment: Agreed, but it's what the webservice returns. I don't know if that can be changed.

Comment: Hmmm, the OP doesn't say that she doesn't have control of the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) method to convert string to double and then you can use the == operator for comparison

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely cast the string into a double before you use it for comparison.

Further double.Equals is a bit tricky because this method takes care of the exact number of digits after the comma of your number which means

```
double d1 = 0.33333d;
double d2 = 1/3;

bool result = double.Equals(d1, d2);
```

will obviously be false although you expect them to be equal.

To avoid this issue I would trim the double with the higher number of digits after the comma down to the one which has fewer digits after the comma.

E.g.:

```
double d1 = 0.167832;
double d2 = 0.1564;
```

would melt into

```
double d1 = 0.1678
double d2 = 0.1564
```

Now you can compare them without worrying.